# Meteor 1.5 : Dynamic Import for Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-packages, dynamic-import

I am having two questions:

1) I want to use Meteor 1.5 Dynamic Import for Blaze but all the examples and tutorials are given for React. So I am confused how exactly it can be used . Can anyone give examples of it.

2) I am using packages from atmospherejs.com like amcharts which I only need at Admin Dashboard side. How to dynamically import them?

Thanks in Advance!

**UPDATE(Solution):**

Below is homepage.html (parent template)

```
<template name="homepage">
  Homepage Content
 {{> Template.dynamic template=content}}    
</template>
```

login.html (child template)

```
<template name="login">
  You're logged in!
</template>
```

login.js

```
import '../homepage/homepage.js';
import './login.html';
API = function () {
  BlazeLayout.render("homepage",{content: 'login'});
}

export { API }
```

main.js

```
LoadLogin = function () {
  import('/imports/modules/common/login/login.js').then(function (api) {
    api.API();
  })
}
```

/lib/route.js

```
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/ostrio:flow-router-extra';
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'homepage',
  action() {
    LoadLogin();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am developing my own admin panel, [Meteor Candy](http://meteorcandy.com), to be driven by dynamic imports, so I am happy to share how I got it working.

First, we have the view.html:

```
<template name="admin">
    Admin
</template>
```

Second, we have our JS logic:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Blaze } from 'meteor/blaze';

import './view.html';

API = {}

API.render = function () {
     Blaze.render(Template.admin, document.body);
}

export { API }
```

Finally, we just need to import that code and trigger our Template to be rendered into the page:

```
openAdmin = function () {
    import('./imports/admins').then(function (api) {
        api.render()
    })
}
```

Once something runs the `openAdmin()` function, the templates will be imported from the server and the render function will be called.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. Can you please share your file structure? Actually I am getting Error on console => Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './imports/admins'

Comment: I have a similar example in this repo, there you could see a typical file structure: https://github.com/msavin/dynamic-import-example

Comment: Thank you so much. I am following your code and till now it is working great.

Answer (score 1):

The basic technique for dynamically importing modules in Meteor 1.5 using Blaze is as follows:

```
Template.theTemplate.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    import("foo").then(Foo => {
      console.log(Foo);
    });
  }
});
```

Make sure you take a close look at how your module is then imported, because apparently some refactoring may be needed when calling it in your code. For example, using "zxcvbn":

**WAS**

```
const result = zxcvbn(pwd);
```

**IS**

```
const result = zxcvbn.default(pwd);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward using example link `https://github.com/thesaucecode/meteor-amcharts-example/blob/master/client/example2.js`, you just have to write the code inside `Template.MYTEMPLATE.onRendered(function(){});`

On top of that you can use `var chart` as reactive-var.

Comment: I am not having problem with displaying Amcharts. I wants to dynamically import amchart after loading of Homepage i.e I don't want Amchart to be a part of my initial meteor bundle. Wanted to load only home page initially and then other modules.